# preg_replace for a time string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

We are using a preg_replace to get a well formated time string. The result should look like this:

`mo-sa9:00-20:00uhr` => `mo-sa 09:00-20:00uhr`

The regex is:

```
preg_replace('=[^\d](\d{1})[.:](\d{2})=U', ' 0${1}:${2}', $norm)
```

The result is: mo-s 09:00-20:00uhr

After many attempts, I found that I couldn't seem to find a pattern that correctly formatted the time string.

The replacement seems to be the problem or am I looking at it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~(?<!\d)(\d)[.:](\d{2})~', ' $1:$2', $norm)
```

Or, if you want to keep the separator char:

```php
preg_replace('~(?<!\d)(\d)([.:])(\d{2})~', ' $1$2$3', $norm)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FFXTYH/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand digit boundary
- `(\d)` - Group 1 (`$1`): a digit
- `([.:])` - Group 2 (`$2`): `.` or `:`
- `(\d{2})` - Group 3 (`$3`): two digits.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/VE5pK):

```php
<?php

$norm = 'mo-sa9:00-20:00uhr';
echo preg_replace('~(?<!\d)(\d)([.:])(\d{2})~', ' $1$2$3', $norm);
// => mo-sa 9:00-20:00uhr
```

Comment: Cool Thanks a lot. And this one only converts strings like "0:00" into "00:00" right?

Answer (score 0):

You can match the part that you want, and assert what should be to the right as well.

Note that you can omit `{1}`, you can write `[^\d]` as `\D` and you don't need the `/U` flag to make quantifiers lazy.

```
\D\K(?=\d[.:]\d{2}\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `\D` Match a non digit and then a single digit
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what is to the right

  - `\d[.:]\d{2}` Match a digit, then either `.` or `:` and 2 digits
  - `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pmh2gy/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Fp3GB)

In the replacement use  `0`

```
$re = '/\D\K(?=\d[.:]\d{2}\b)/';
$norm = 'mo-sa9:00-20:00uhr';

echo preg_replace($re, " 0", $norm);
```

Output

```
mo-sa 09:00-20:00uhr
```

---

If the string is always formatted like this, you could also opt for a precise match:

```
\b[a-z]+-[a-z]+\K\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\duhr\b
```

In the replacement use the 2 capture groups with a space in between.

```
$re = '/\b[a-z]+-[a-z]+\K\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\duhr\b/';
$norm = 'mo-sa9:00-20:00uhr';

echo preg_replace($re, " 0$0", $norm); // mo-sa 09:00-20:00uhr
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H524DY/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/WHDW5)

Answer (score 0):

The current issue is that `[^\d]` is matching the `a` but you do nothing with it so it is lost on replacing.

I would use `preg_replace_callback` and use datetime functions to ensure leading zeros as needed.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(\d\d?:\d\d)-(\d\d?:\d\d)/', function($match){
    return ' ' . date('H:i', strtotime($match[1])) . '-' . date('H:i', strtotime($match[2])); 
}, 'mo-sa9:00-20:00uhr');
```

https://3v4l.org/K1voc